# Compile error building react-native on Windows 10

Tags: android, react-native, windows-10

I'm trying to execute the following script in a React Native project:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

But get the following error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I can only assume a script somewhere in there assumed it's being run in a OSX/Linux terminal, but I'm unable to tell which and how to fix it. Does React Native not support being built on Windows by any chance?

Comment: You need to remove the ./ in your command. Try running this: ```react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && gradlew clean assembleDebug```

Comment: Damn it was that, I totally thought ./ was valid syntax in powershell/cmd. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per @tomerpacific's comment, the solution was changing the command to

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

It appear `./command` is not valid Powershell syntax? Closing this as solved.